# Simplify 4 if/else checks on two booleans

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

I have a situation like this in my code:

```
bool a, b, result;
... // a and b are set
if(!a &&! b)
    result = functionOne() ;
else if(!a && b)
    result = functionTwo();
else if(a &&! b)
    result = functionThree();
else
    result = functionFour();
```

Is there any way to simplify/shorten this code? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to shorten the code? It will likely come at the cost of clarity.

Comment: @qwr Actually I'm just doing some projects for learning purposes, so I'm trying various things

Comment: One option is nesting the checks: `if (!a) { if (!b) functionOne(); else functionTwo(); } else { if (!b) functionThree(); else functionFour(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [ternary operator](https://www.w3schools.in/cplusplus-program/conditional-ternary-operator/):

```
bool a, b, result;
// a and b are set
result = a && b ? functionOne() : b ?functionTwo() : a ? functionThree() : functionFour();
```

Use it only for simple if else tasks and not for complicated ones because it's can get messy really fast.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make use of some implications:

```
bool a, b, result;
... // a and b are set
if(a && b)
    result = functionFour();
else if(b)
    result = functionTwo();
else if(a)
    result = functionThree();
else
    result = functionOne();
```

Explanation: If not both `a` and `b` are true, one must be false. In that case, if `b` is true, `a` *must* be false so there is no need to evaluate it redundantly.

Answer (score 2):

As learning is your purpose here is a "simplification" using lookup table:

```
#include <iostream>

bool functionOne()
{
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  return true;
}
bool functionTwo()
{
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  return true;
}
bool functionThree()
{
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  return true;
}
bool functionFour()
{
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  using F = bool (*)();
  constexpr F lookup[2][2] = {{functionOne, functionTwo},
                              {functionThree, functionFour}};

  bool a = true, b = false, result;
  result = lookup[a][b]();           // <- the simplification
}
```

prints:

```
functionThree
```

as expected.

**Explanation:** it uses a 2-dimensional array of function pointers.

**Note:** it works as C++ standard explicitly says that during conversion bool -> int (your array index), false is converted to zero and true to one.

> ```
> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
> the value true is converted to the value one of the destination type
> (note that if the destination type is int, this is an integer
> promotion, not an integer conversion).
> ```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Answer (score 2):

This question is really opinion based, so there are many possible solutions that - depending on individual preferences - may be chosen.

You can always test a single variable in the `if`, and then use a ternary operator

```
 if (!a)
     result = (!b) ? functionOne() : functionTwo();
 else
     result = (!b) ? functionThree() : functionFour();
```

This has a (possible) advantage of only needing to evaluate each of `!a` and `!b` exactly once at run time.

If you want to eliminate the negations (some may consider that is better for readability, particularly since it is unusual for the names of functions to imply an ordering of them) the code can be turned into

```
 if (a)
     result = b ? functionFour() : functionThree();
 else
     result = b ? functionTwo() : functionOne();
```

which brings us to options of eliminating the `if` statement entirely.

```
 // with negation

 result = !a ? ((!b) ? functionOne() : functionTwo()) : 
              ((!b) ? functionThree() : functionFour());

 // without negation

 result = a ? (b ? functionFour() : functionThree()) : 
              (b ? functionTwo() : functionOne());
```

Another option that comes to mind would be

```
 int index = 2*a + b;
 if (index == 0)
     result = functionOne();
 else if (index == 1)
     result = functionTwo();
 else if (index == 2)
     result = functionThree();
 else if (index == 3)
     result = functionFour();
```

which can be simplified by using a one dimensional array

```
  using func = bool(*)();    // C++11 and later.   typedef bool (*func)() for all C++ standards
  func table[] = {functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree, functionFour};
  result = table[2*a + b]();
```

Comment: The last suggestion also lends itself well to `switch` (for when we have more than a bunch of compatible functions to choose from).

Comment: @TobySpeight - I take it you mean the second last suggestion (using the `if`/`else if`).   I agree.  Another member has provided the `switch` form you refer to, so I won't replicate it.

Comment: The last suggestion - combining into `int index = 2*a + b`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a switch:

```
 int index = 2*a + b;
 switch (index) {
     case 0: result = functionOne();  break;
     case 1: result = functionTwo();  break;
     case 2: result = functionThree();break;
     case 3: result = functionFour(); break;
 }
```